# Not able to build aura project, failing aura-util test cases

Tags: lightning

I have cloned the [Auro Github repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura) and tried to build by running `mvn clean install` but could not build it due to below tests failed, any help would be appreciated.

```
Results :

Failed tests:
  IOUtilTest.testDelete:88 test cleanup failed
  DateServiceTest.testGetDateISO8601Converter:178->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:208->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DateServiceTest/testGetDateISO8601Converter.txt
Differences:

diff:

  DateServiceTest.testGetDateStyleConverter_locale_dateStyle:254->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:208->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DateServiceTest/testGetDateStyleConverter_locale_dateStyle.txt
Differences:

diff:

  DateServiceTest.testGetDateTimeISO8601Converter:157->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:208->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DateServiceTest/testGetDateTimeISO8601Converter.txt
Differences:

diff:

  DateServiceTest.testGetDateTimeStyleConverter_locale_dateStyle_timeStyle:325->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:208->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DateServiceTest/testGetDateTimeStyleConverter_locale_dateStyle_timeStyle.txt
Differences:

diff:

  DateServiceTest.testGetGenericISO8601Converter:221->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:208->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DateServiceTest/testGetGenericISO8601Converter.txt
Differences:

diff:

  DateServiceTest.testGetPatternConverter_locale_pattern:360->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:208->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DateServiceTest/testGetPatternConverter_locale_pattern.txt
Differences:

diff:

  DateServiceTest.testGetTimeStyleConverter_locale_timeStyle:288->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:208->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DateServiceTest/testGetTimeStyleConverter_locale_timeStyle.txt
Differences:

diff:

  CommonJavascriptGroupImplTest.testBasicInitialization:82 Addition of a valid javascript file failed
  DirectiveBasedJavascriptGroupTest.testJavascriptGenerationDevelopment:118->doTestJavascriptGeneration:183->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DirectiveBasedJavascriptGroupTest/testJavascriptGenerationDevelopment/testDummy_dev.js
Differences:

diff:

  DirectiveBasedJavascriptGroupTest.testJavascriptGenerationProduction:113->doTestJavascriptGeneration:183->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DirectiveBasedJavascriptGroupTest/testJavascriptGenerationProduction/testDummy_prod.js
Differences:

diff:

  DirectiveParserTest.testAllKindsOfDirectiveGenerate:145->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DirectiveParserTest/testAllKindsOfDirectiveGenerate_test.js
Differences:

diff:

  DirectiveParserTest.testMultilineDirective:113->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DirectiveParserTest/testMultilineDirective.js
Differences:

diff:

  DirectiveParserTest.testZeroDirectiveTypes:48->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/DirectiveParserTest/testZeroDirectiveTypes.js
Differences:

diff:

  JavascriptGeneratorTest.testGeneration:29->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/JavascriptGeneratorTest/testGeneration_mock1.js
Differences:

diff:

  IfDirectiveTest.testJSSourceWithIfDirective:65->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/IfDirectiveTest/testJSSourceWithIfDirective_test.js
Differences:

diff:

  IncludeDirectiveTest.testIncludeDirective:126->UnitTestCase.goldFileText:218 Gold file differences found, review updated gold file before committing: file:/C:/Users/User/salesforce/aura/aura-util/src/test/results/IncludeDirectiveTest/testIncludeDirective_test.js
Differences:

diff:

  ResourceLoaderTest.testCacheDirParentIsAFile:235
Tests in error:
  DirectoryCleanerTest.testDirectoryCleanerWithProtectedDirectory:73 ╗ UnsupportedOperation
org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest.testCacheDirParentNotWritable(org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest)
  Run 1: ResourceLoaderTest.testCacheDirParentNotWritable:250 Should have failed to cache resource
  Run 2: ResourceLoaderTest>UnitTestCase.legacyTearDown:110->tearDown:111 ╗ DeleteFailed

org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest.testGetResourceCachedMissingVersion(org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest)
  Run 1: ResourceLoaderTest.testGetResourceCachedMissingVersion:428->createJarResourceLoader:137->createJarFromFolder:536 ╗ URISyntax
  Run 2: ResourceLoaderTest>UnitTestCase.legacyTearDown:110->tearDown:111 ╗ DeleteFailed

org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest.testGetResourceNotCached(org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest)
  Run 1: ResourceLoaderTest.testGetResourceNotCached:285->createJarResourceLoader:137->createJarFromFolder:536 ╗ URISyntax
  Run 2: ResourceLoaderTest>UnitTestCase.legacyTearDown:110->tearDown:111 ╗ DeleteFailed

org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest.testObstructedRecurisvely(org.auraframework.util.resource.ResourceLoaderTest)
  Run 1: ResourceLoaderTest.testObstructedRecurisvely:479->createJarResourceLoader:137->createJarFromFolder:536 ╗ URISyntax
  Run 2: ResourceLoaderTest>UnitTestCase.legacyTearDown:110->tearDown:111 ╗ DeleteFailed


Tests run: 234, Failures: 18, Errors: 5, Skipped: 2

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Aura Framework ..................................... SUCCESS [01:04 min]
[INFO] aura-interfaces .................................... SUCCESS [ 50.949 s]
[INFO] aura-spring ........................................ SUCCESS [ 49.861 s]
[INFO] aura-util .......................................... FAILURE [01:01 min]
[INFO] aura ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-impl-expression ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-impl .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-tools ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-components .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-modules ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-resources ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-integration-test .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] aura-jetty ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] archetype for Aura-based "hello, world" ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-21T21:58:41+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project aura-util: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\User\salesforce\aura\aura-util\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: I believe this has been logged here : https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues/111 but I don't see any updates on this.